# Is $\mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho) = 0$ $\forall$ $\rho$ $\in\{\rho: \langle\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\rangle_{\rho}= 0\}$ true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

[**Context**: I have observed the fact, $\mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho) = 0$ $\forall$ $\rho$ $\in\{\rho: \langle\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\rangle_{\rho}= 0\}$ *(meaning of the symbols are below)* true numerically, which I have done using python and have the Jupyter notebook of the same. I wanted to attach it to this post but don't know how. I wanted to know the mathematical reason behind it. I am stating it as a theorem below. How can we prove it formally?]

**Theorem:** Consider a finite-dimensional separable Hilbert space of arbitrary dimension $N$.

Defining operator $V\geq0$ as a positive semi-definite Hermitian operator which is diagonalizable and can be represented as in the block diagonal form as $V = \left(\begin{matrix} V_{00}&0\\0 &V_{11} \end{matrix}\right)$ where $V_{00}$ and $V_{11}$ are also diagonal and $V_{00} - V_{11} < 0$.

Defining the operator $L = \left(\begin{matrix}0&V_{11}\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$ and $H_{0}$ which is a arbitrary system Hamiltonian. Assuming$[H_{0}, V] = 0$, the superoperator  $\mathcal{G}_{H_{0},L} = i[H_{0}, V]+ \mathcal{L}_{L}(V)$ = $ \mathcal{L}_{L}(V) = L^{\dagger}VL - \frac{1}{2}\{L^{\dagger}L, V\}$. We can compute $\mathcal{L}_{L}(V) = \left(\begin{matrix}0&0
\\0&(V_{00} - V_{11})V_{11}V_{11}\end{matrix}\right)$ $\because$ $V_{00} - V_{11} < 0$ $\implies$ $\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\leq 0$.

Then, $\forall$ $\rho$ $\in\{\rho: \langle\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\rangle_{\rho}=0\}$, prove that $\mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho) = 0$. Here,
$\mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho) = L\rho L^{\dagger} - \frac{1}{2}\{L^{\dagger}L, \rho\}$.

*(What I think might be the case)*
\begin{align*} 
\langle\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\rangle_{\rho}=0\\
\implies Tr(\mathcal{L}_{L}(V)\rho) = 0\\
\implies Tr(V\mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho))) = 0 && \because\text{(Cyclic property of trace)}\\
\implies \mathcal{L}^{*}_{L}(\rho) = 0
\end{align*}

*Is my guess correct?*

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide some context…

Comment: @ ZeroTheHero I edited the post further. Is my conclusion in the last three steps correct in general.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker $L$ is Lindblad operator, and $X$ is a Positive definite Hermitian operator. Sorry $V$ and $X$ are the same. I have edited that as well.

Comment: What do we know about non-script $L$?

Comment: @doublefelix $L$ is some Lindblad collapse operator. Just wanted to know that we can conclude that for a general Lindblad superoperator $\mathcal{L}$ which I have written in the last part of the post.

Comment: you should include these comments in your questions.  Comments get deleted….

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Okay, will do that.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker The premise here is that if we prove that for some positive semidefinite operator $X$ this $\mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathcal{L}(X)\rho(t)\right) = 0$ then can we conclude $mathcal{L}^{*}(X)\rho(t)\right) = 0$

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Edited that in the post.